# Create animations then update the model?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, linked-data

So basically I have a model rigged and set to animate. I have someone else that is going to work on the animations, while i finish the model (sculpting and textures).
Would it be possible for him to finish or save his animations and simply apply them to the updated model (or vice versa)?